# Facebook comment array contains null values. How do I handle this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the Facebook graph API, and I have one comment array. This comment array has a lot of null values. How can I handle this?

Here is my code.

```
 NSArray *commentData =[TheMainData valueForKey:@"comments"];

          NSArray *thecommentdata =[commentData valueForKey:@"data"];
           //NSLog(@"%@",thecommentdata);


        NSMutableArray *themaincommentdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

              themaincommentdata =[[thecommentdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message" ];

        NSLog(@"%@",themaincommentdata);
```

When I log my `thecommentdata` array, I get the following results:

```
(
                {
            "can_remove" = 1;
            "created_time" = "2014-04-30T13:22:45+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 100000329153640;
                name = "Ishant Tiwari";
            };
            id = "241720846019272_241721019352588";
            "like_count" = 0;
            message = "waoooo iron man comment .................";
            "user_likes" = 0;
        },
                {
            "can_remove" = 1;
            "created_time" = "2014-04-30T13:25:16+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 100000329153640;
                name = "Ishant Tiwari";
            };
            id = "241720846019272_241721626019194";
            "like_count" = 0;
            message = "2nd comment";
            "user_likes" = 0;
        }
    ),
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
        (
                {
            "can_remove" = 1;
            "created_time" = "2014-04-25T05:14:34+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 100005440749818;
                name = "Birjesh Sharma";
            };
            id = "240287756162581_240287929495897";
            "like_count" = 0;
            message = "comment by nishant";
            "user_likes" = 0;
        }
    ),
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>",
    "<null>"
)
```

The problem that no comments can be imported from the `thecommentdata` to the `themaincommentdata`array after I hit the null values.

Here is the log output for the `themaincommentdata`array:

```
(
    "waoooo iron man comment .................",
    "2nd comment"
)
2014-05-01 11:31:34.819 Dozo[741:3b0b] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
```

How do I handle this sort of a problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to use something like this:

```
-(BOOL)isNullForObject:(id)obj{

    return (!obj || obj = (id)[NSNull null]); 

}


id fieldX =...

if (![self isNullForObject:fieldX]){

    // Do your stuff...

}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try-catch` block or a `if` condition

`try-catch` block if you have any exceptions

```
@try {
    themaincommentdata =[[thecommentdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message" ];
    ....
    ....
}

@catch(NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Some NULL Values");
}
```

Using `if` condition

```
if (![[thecommentdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message" ] == [NSNull null]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[thecommentdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"message" ]);
}
```